# Seeding the Initial SVN synch with flat files

Tags: svn

I have a remote user that I am trying to add to our SVN repo. They are far away and the repo is very large. It would take many days/weeks for the initial synch to happen if we had to do it over the internet.

In the past we have copied the svn repo directory on to a USB sick and send it via snail mail to the new user. But unfortunately this time we forgot to include the Hidden files (all the SVN repo files) with the archive. So the new user has all the files from the SVN repo but non of the SVN system files.

Is there anyway we can use these files to initially seed the SVN repo, so the new user will not have to download all the files from the SVN repo over the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You **need** the `.svn` metadata/control directory. There's a sqlite database in there that manages the working copy including the pristine copies of your files.

Make another USB stick & ship it out.

Comment: This is what I expected.